# Rails test upload with paperclip-dropbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, paperclip, dropbox

I am using paperclip-dropbox gem to store my assets. I want to create a test to ensure assets are properly destroyed if the destroy checkbox is checked. 
I can see on dropbox the image is uploaded and deleted but just after it's created again. Don't understand why.

**Here is my test file**:

```
require 'test_helper'

#
# == Admin namespace
#
module Admin
  #
  # == SettingsController test
  #
  class SettingsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
    include Devise::TestHelpers

    setup :initialize_test

    #
    # == Avatar
    #
    test 'should be able to upload logo' do
      upload_dropbox_paperclip_attachment
      setting = assigns(:setting)
      assert setting.logo?
      assert_equal 'bart.png', setting.logo_file_name
      assert_equal 'image/png', setting.logo_content_type
    end

    test 'should be able to destroy logo' do
      upload_dropbox_paperclip_attachment
      remove_dropbox_paperclip_attachment
    end

    private

    def initialize_test
      @setting = settings(:one)
      @administrator = users(:bob)
      sign_in @administrator
    end

    def upload_dropbox_paperclip_attachment
      puts '=== Uploading logo to Dropbox'
      attachment = fixture_file_upload 'images/bart.png', 'image/png'
      patch :update, id: @setting, setting: { logo: attachment }
    end

    def remove_dropbox_paperclip_attachment
      puts '=== Removing logo from Dropbox'
      patch :update, id: @setting, setting: { logo: nil, delete_logo: '1' }
      assert_not assigns(:setting).logo?
    end
  end
end
```

Do someone know what is wrong with this test ?
Am I in the right way trying to test for dropbox or should I test only in local ? the documentation for paperclip-dropbox doesn't give any information about testing.
Thanks

**My project**:

- Rails 4.2.3
- Ruby 2.2.2

Comment: On the Dropbox side of things, the Dropbox API doesn't know that this is a testing setup, it just receives and services the Dropbox API calls. You may want to start by adding some extra logging to see what API calls are being made. You can also check the revisions list on the Dropbox web site to see what is happening for the file: https://www.dropbox.com/help/11

Comment: Thanks. I finally decided to use local storage for development / test and use dropbox for staging / production